# UEFI Boot repair failed

Tags: partitioning, grub2, uefi, gparted

My boot repair to UEFI failed. I don't know why.
Somehow, my Boot repair, launched temporarily from usb, doesn't seem to recognize my 'bios grub' flag.

My partition amount looks a bit messy.
In short, I have my windows at /dev/sdb2 and my Kubuntu at /dev/sdb1 .

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/CnTz7HFgcK/

I had a legacy setup mode, but I had only 1 screen supported under Windows 10.
I did some changes with "diskpart" of Microsoft, and I can run that Windows 10 now with 2 displays active ( UEFI mode).
But I don't have access any more to my Kubuntu on SSD, or maybe when I switch again to legacy mode, but how can I configure GParted better, to make the grub repair a success for UEFI boot type?

Comment: Maybe I should call Microsoft to solve the display problem with legacy and the shut down problem! If they solve those bugs, I can boot then in legacy mode without mess!

Comment: You cannot mix UEFI and BIOS boot on same drive. Windows was UEFI boot as drive is gpt which means Windows is UEFI and you have Windows UEFI boot entry in UEFI. Ubuntu  is in CSM/BIOS/Legacy boot mode as you have bios_grub and grub in gpt's protective MBR and in sdb1's PBR - partition boot sector. It looks like you deleted ESP - efi system partition that had Windows UEFI boot files. It may have been sda1, but that is now NTFS, not FAT32 which is required for UEFI. Do not keep switching modes. Only use UEFI boot mode. Recreate an ESP & reinstall Windows boot loader using your Windows repair.

Comment: My goal is to keep UEFI boot mode, but now I use: Windows in UEFI mode and Linux in Legacy mode. I'll try to recreate an esp and windows repair. I deleted the ESP to be able to boot my new Windows in UEFI mode.

Comment: The ESP is required for Windows to boot in UEFI boot mode. And for you to reinstall grub in UEFI boot mode to boot in UEFI mode. If you have ESP, you can use Boot-Repair in UEFI mode to totally reinstall grub and convert to UEFI boot.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't execute the windows command "bcdboot" correctly.
I errased my 2 SSD's completely to start from zero. I updated the grid tables then (GTP).
I did a reinstallation of windows 10 (UEFI at bios), shrinked it to make some space for Xubuntu (ext4) and installed Xubuntu (UEFI at bios).
In the past, I was quite often able to install Windows after Linux, to repair then the boot but I had then those 2 then seperated on 2 disks. Now, I wanted both on my fastest SSD and now I have both with UEFI there.